# prefix url in Swagger module

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs

I am using nest js and swagger as documentation but  Swagger module ignores setGlobalPrefix().
in my environemnt the api prefix is API_PREFIX=/api/v2 , I have no problem when testing it with postman cause the endpoints/url does work which is http://localhost:5000/api/v2/user/profile

but the swagger cant get the /api/v2 prefix , the swagger request url is  http://localhost:5000/user/profile which is wrong.

Any idea ? Thank you for any help.

## settings

````
```const SWAGGER_PREFIX = '/docs';

async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  if (!process.env.SWAGGER_ENABLE || process.env.SWAGGER_ENABLE === '1') {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define
    createSwagger(app);
  }

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: process.env.API_CORS || '*'
    })
  );

  app.setGlobalPrefix(process.env.API_PREFIX || API_DEFAULT_PREFIX);

  const logInterceptor = app.select(CommonModule).get(LogInterceptor);
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(logInterceptor);

  await app.listen(process.env.API_PORT || API_DEFAULT_PORT);
}

function createSwagger(app: INestApplication) {
  const version = require('../package.json').version || '';

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle(SWAGGER_TITLE)
    .setDescription(SWAGGER_DESCRIPTION)
    .setVersion(version)
    .setBasePath(process.env.API_PREFIX || API_DEFAULT_PREFIX)
    .addBearerAuth()
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup(SWAGGER_PREFIX, app, document);[![enter image description here][1]][1]


//swagger - the request url is http://localhost:5000/user/profile
which is supposed to be  http://localhost:5000/api/v2/user/profile
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure that this line

```
  app.setGlobalPrefix(process.env.API_PREFIX || API_DEFAULT_PREFIX);
```

and this line, evaluates the same

```
.setBasePath(process.env.API_PREFIX || API_DEFAULT_PREFIX)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create the swagger (call to `createSwagger` in function `bootstrap`) after having set the global prefix of your api (call to `setGlobalPrefix` in function `bootstrap`). It will then find the api prefix on its own a prepend any request with it.

```html
async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {

    const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);

    app.setGlobalPrefix(process.env.API_PREFIX || API_DEFAULT_PREFIX);

    if (!process.env.SWAGGER_ENABLE || process.env.SWAGGER_ENABLE === 'true') {
        createSwagger(app);
    }

    await app.listen(process.env.API_PORT || API_DEFAULT_PORT);
}

function createSwagger(app: INestApplication) {

    const version = require('../package.json').version || '';

    const options = new DocumentBuilder()
        .setTitle(SWAGGER_TITLE)
        .setDescription(SWAGGER_DESCRIPTION)
        .setVersion(version)
        .build();

    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
    SwaggerModule.setup(SWAGGER_PREFIX, app, document);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of setGlobalPrefix was in correct.

First setGlobalPrefix should be called (it will update app object) then setup swagger document then swagger will populate global prefix.